# Firebase phone authentication not working in android

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase-authentication

I am making an chatting app. in it i have added phone auth from firebase. when i click on login it asks otp in emulator. i add otp of test number i have created it does not redirect me to next page. I checked Logcat and it says that verificationId is null.

it is my first page code where user enters his phone number-

```
package com.example.nowchat;
```

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.nowchat.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityLoginBinding binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    binding.phoneBox.requestFocus();

    binding.getotp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void  onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, OTP.class);

            intent.putExtra("phone", binding.phoneBox.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

this is code of page where user enters otp and is not redirected to 3rd page-

```
package com.example.nowchat;
```

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.nowchat.databinding.ActivityOTPBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.mukesh.OnOtpCompletionListener;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class OTP extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityOTPBinding binding;
FirebaseAuth auth;

String verificationId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityOTPBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());




    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
    binding.phoneLbl.setText("Verify " + phoneNumber);

    PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(OTP.this)
            .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) 
{

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verifyId, @NonNull 
PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(verifyId, forceResendingToken);


                   verificationId = verifyId;
                   //verificationId ="and";

                }

            }).build();

    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

    binding.otpView.setOtpCompletionListener(new OnOtpCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOtpCompleted(String otp) {
            Log.i("abcd", "verification id is"+ verificationId);
            Log.i("abcd", "otp id is" + otp);
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otp);
            auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(OTP.this, SetupProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finishAffinity();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(OTP.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
     });

    }
}
```

here are images of activities-

[it is first activity]

[second activity]

Answer (score 0):

check logs if everything is ok

and make sure to enable SafetyNet
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com

it should work properly when you have complete all the required SafetyNet steps